# Pre 100 Rep: Answer own question suggestion/advice popup

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, new-users, self-answer

While there are other pre 100 rep answer own question threads, none that I've seen put forward what I'd like to ask.

I have only just recently joined so my reputation isn't large, so user privilege affected the quality of a question/answer in a negative way. The situation this formed from was when I created a question and before the wait time to be able to answer my own question was passed I managed to solve my problem. As I could not add the answer for another 6 hours I edited the question to include the answer to the question, to which I would properly add the answer afterwards. I felt it was reasonable to make the edit until such a time to prevent people from wasting their time trying to figure it out, when I already had an answer. However this attracted a moderators attention, the edit was removed, his reasoning posted that I should answer using the post an answer. However what was asked of me was just impossible to do due to the way the site was constructed for people under 100 rep.

Now from what I've gathered from other questions, users are restricted from creating answers this early to prevent them from creating lots of answers and treating the site as a forum more than anything else.

From what I can see a user can make more than one answer for a question, however what I feel would be a better solution that still addresses the problem would be to limit users under 100 rep to only 1 answer a question.

Even if this is not possible it may be wise to have some form of advice regarding if the edit is about an answer popup to a user under 100 rep when they try to edit their question. Having an agreed upon popup for new users wanting to answer their question before the time limit has passed as to prevent un-needed time wastage for other users would be helpful and help keep the site focused.

Is this sort of solution worthwhile or should things remain exactly as they are?

Comment: Just a note to your answer-edit: You could have added something along the lines of `I'll convert this to an answer as soon as the system let's me.`, it would prevent such misunderstandings. On the other side Will could have seen that you're not able to post the answer. But we're all humans here and there's no one to blame (in my opinion).

Comment: Yeah I don't feel anyone was to blame, apart from myself for not being as clear about the edit as I could have been.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just wait until the time limit expires? Someone might come up with a better answer.

If you really want to let people know you've found a solution adding a **comment** rather than editing the question is probably the best solution.

Just to clarify - don't leave the **solution** in the comment, just that you've found one and will be posting an answer when you are able.

Comment: The problem with adding a comment is how the comment length is restricted to 600 characters. While someone can say they have found a solution, other people who want to know the solution to the problem are then forced to wait. If a system for new users affects older users, a change of some sort should be made. Users will only encounter this problem at most once or twice before they have hit the rep, but if it's a recurring problem then it is better to address it as soon as possible. If someone has a better answer then they can still answer, as the accepted answer wait will still be in place.

Comment: @Stuart - don't add the *solution* in the comment, just that you've found one.

Answer (score 2):

Just a silly idea of mine, but maybe we should change the text of the button from

> Answer Your Question

to

> Add the solution to your own Question

or something along those lines.